# How to override default sort order in scoped_collection of active admin 0.5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have the following code in my events.rb. By default I am setting sort_order as updated_at_desc.

But if url is has a parameter ride_id (http://localhost:3000/admin/events?ride_id=3009) I need to sort it based on created_at asc.

It not working. Its still fetching the results with sort_order updated_at_desc. How can this be done. Please help.

The below code was working on the previous version of active admin I used, But When I updated it to 0.5.0, I am having this trouble.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
  config.sort_order = 'updated_at_desc'
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      if params[:ride_id].present?
        end_of_association_chain.select('events.*').where('events.booking_id = ?', params[:ride_id]).order('created_at asc')
      else
       end_of_association_chain.select('events.*')
    end
  end
end
```

end

I also used the reorder function

```
end_of_association_chain.select('events.*').where('events.booking_id = ?', params[:ride_id]).reorder('created_at asc')
```

still I am not able to override the default sorting by updated_at_desc. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're setup somewhere uses something like:

```
default_scope order: '... DESC'
```

you can use

```
.unscoped
```

like this:

```
end_of_association_chain.select('events.*').unscoped.where...
```

At least that's what fixed my similar problem.

Notice the following post that states using default_scope is a bad idea, precisely because of what I/we experienced:

http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2012/03/be-careful-using-default_scope-and-order.html

I hope this helps,
TheMahrvin